# Magento SOAP calls Ignoring filters

Tags: soap-api-v2

We fetch orders from magento from several clients on hourly basis. With most of our clients it works perfectly. But with two of them i am facing a weird issue.

For them magento ignores all the filters (order_status/time range) and fetches all the orders. But this happens at a specific time of the day. For one client it happens everyday at 7pm and for other 9pm.

This happens every day at that exact time (give or take 2 minutes). And for the rest of the times it works perfectly. I am not a magento expert and i do not have access to their systems.

Any help would be appreciated